# Appending a string of HTML+Javascript to an element causes strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

http://jsfiddle.net/PeKdr/

Having a Javascript variable containing both HTML and Javascript causes some strangeness in the result window. Neither of the buttons, the one that calls `appendTheString()`, nor the one that calls `springAnAlert()`, function at all.

I expected this fiddle to append the new `babby` div to the `foo` div, as well as the script that would cause the alert box to come up with the button inside the `babby` div is pressed.

Comment: Your jsfiddle was broken: javascript was inserted in the html source and it parsed the `</script>` inside js code. Here is corrected version: http://jsfiddle.net/PeKdr/2/

Comment: Here to see it works (no wrap): http://jsfiddle.net/PeKdr/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have `</script>` inside a script, because the `</script>` ends the script. Even if it's in quotes.

So the answer is to cut the string into pieces, none of which contains an entire end tag.

```
function append() {
    var stringToAppend = "<"+"div class='babby'>The Babby Div!<"+
        "/div><script>alert('This alert never happens!');<"+"/script>";
  $('.foo').append(stringToAppend);
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PeKdr/5/

Edit: oh, I see the very same solution was already given in a comment. But I swear I never saw the comment until I published this answer!

Comment: What!? Why would anyone want it to parse that tag even when it's in quotes? Thank you!

Comment: The parser doesn't know which characters are quotes and which are not. It also doesn't know about javascript comments and things like that. In fact, it doesn't parse the contents at all; all it knows is that a script element ends with `</script>`.

Comment: There are solutions... one is to put the content of the script in a `<![CDATA[` block, as the jsfiddle site does. However, `<![CDATA[` blocks are an XML feature, so they don't work in HTML, only in XHTML! People tend to forget that.

Comment: So complicated. I have a variable similar to the `stringToAppend` above, but I get it using jQuery's .ajax() function, so I'm not sure how I would edit out the `</script>`'s in that situation.

Comment: If it's a variable you get from elsewhere, there are no problems. It's is just the literal string `</script>` in the script text (or to be precise, any end tag) that causes the issue.

Comment: So even though the variable that I get elsewhere contains `</script>`, it'll be fine? If so, I'm even more confused as to why I'm having problems with this, but in that case, my problems are irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle maybe what you want. 
http://jsfiddle.net/PeKdr/8/

```
$("#button").click(function () {
   $('.foo').append("<div class='babby'>The Babby Div!</div>\<script\>alert(1);\<\/script\>");
});
window.showAlert = function(){
   $('.foo').append("<div class='babby'>The Babby Div!</div>\<script\>alert(2);\<\/script\>");
}
```